# Shiny visNetwork conditional layout - getting around incompatible options

Tags: r, shiny, igraph, visnetwork

I'm building a Shiny app displaying interactive networks with `visNetwork` and I'd like to give users the option to choose between two `igraph` layouts. The problem is the additional argument required for one layout is an unused argument for the other and I can't seem to get rid of it conditionally.

```
library(igraph)
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

# generate data
iGr <- make_graph("Meredith")
visGr <- toVisNetworkData(iGr)

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  # layout options
  radioButtons(
    inputId="grLayout",
    label="View in:",
    choices=list(
      "Graph layout"="layout_with_graphopt",
      "Ellipse layout"="layout_in_circle"
    ),
    selected="layout_with_graphopt"
  ),
  visNetworkOutput("netPlot")
)

# server
server <- function(input, output){
  output$netPlot <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(visGr$nodes, visGr$edges) %>%
      visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout,
                      charge=0.1 # <- here's my problem
                      )
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I need the `charge` argument for the `layout_with_graphopt` option with my real data to make the the visualization readable, but it throws an "unused argument (charge = 0.1)" error with the `layout_in_circle` option. I've tried the two variations without success.

This one won't run at all and throws an 'argument "graph" is missing, with no default' error:

```
  output$netPlot <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(visGr$nodes, visGr$edges) %>%
      {if (input$grLayout=="layout_with_graphopt") {
        visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout,
                        charge=0.1)
      } else {
        visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout)
      }}
  })
```

This one throws an "unused argument (charge = NULL)" error for the `layout_in_circle` option. (I get something similar if I try `NA`):

```
  output$netPlot <- renderVisNetwork({
    chargeVal <- if (input$grLayout=="layout_with_graphopt") {0.1} else {NULL}
    visNetwork(visGr$nodes, visGr$edges) %>%
      visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout,
                      charge=chargeVal)
  })
```

I'd rather not do an `if else` on the whole `renderVisNetwork` block because the real one is quite lengthy with a fair number of bells and whistles, and the `charge` argument would be the only difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick is to stick everything *except* the `visIgraphLayout` lines into a `visNetwork` object, then pipe conditional versions of `visIgraphLayout` onto the back of it:

```
  output$netPlot <- renderVisNetwork({
    plot1 <- visNetwork(visGr$nodes, visGr$edges)
    # can add whatever other bells and whistles needed before if/else if
    # conditional layout:
    if (input$grLayout=="layout_with_graphopt"){
      plot2 <- plot1 %>%
        visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout,
                        charge=0.1)
    } else if (input$grLayout=="layout_in_circle") {
      plot2 <- plot1 %>%
        visIgraphLayout(physics=FALSE, type="square", layout=input$grLayout)
    }
    return(plot2)
  })
```